# Will webjob scale-in kill "busy" instances?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

Let's say I have a webjob that consumes messages from a storage queue. I am planning a scale rule to scale-out when my queue has too many messages waiting to be picked up.

Some of the messages will take a long time to process.

My question is... If scale-out happens and that the scale-in rule kicks in (when the nbr of message in the queue decrease), will Azure wait until the messages have finished processing before killing the instances or it will just kill the instances right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 01/20:**

For auto-scaling, it doesn't matter, it will wait for the instance to finish it's job.

But for manually scale-in, it does not wait but kill it right away.

---

Original:

For manually scale-in, no, it does not kill the busy instance. Azure WebApp / webjobs should use a specified LoadBalance strategy for multiple instances, and it will balance the workload and route the queue messages to the 3 instances respectively. That means the 3 instances will work in parallel.

I didn't find any official document about this, but it's easy to test it out.

I set up a queue trigger webjob, and upload it as continuous in azure. After scale out, you can see the 3 instances are all working.

Note: the instance id 940246 is the original one, the other 2 instances id 4c7ed0 / f3753c comes after scale out.

In the kudu site, the 3 instances are listed there. Screenshot as below:

[image]

In the webjob logs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes that's how the scale out works but when it's time to scale in, if the instances are busy processing messages (messages that take let's say 10 minutes to process), will they be killed right away or Azure will wait for them to finish their current process?

Comment: @alexbf Regarding this, I just contacted MS support, and here is the feedback: `If you simply reduce the instance, then the instances will be killed directly without any work.`  It means that it will be killed right away.

Comment: Excellent but if the instance is currently processing messages it would be detrimental to kill the instance right away. Does the scaling engine waits for the instance to finish it's work before killing it?

Comment: @alexbf, are you using auto-scale or manually scale? If auto-scale, it doesn't matter, it will wait for the instance to finish it's job. But for manually scale-in, it does not wait but kill it right away. Hope it helps.

Comment: It's automatic scaling yes. Thank you for the precision. You can edit your answer to add these details and I'll accept it.